# How to display the custom post's selected custom taxonomy inside the loop without the link and echo?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Here's the code snippet that I am trying to sort out:

```
$args=array(
      'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'meta_key'         => 'custom_meta_key',
      'meta_value'       => 'on',
    );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
        $custom_taxonomy = the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy');
    endwhile;
```

however, this echoes

```
<a rel="tag" href="http://myweb/custom_taxonomy/selectedTerm/">selectedTerm</a>
```

but I only need the `selectedTerm`

Using `strip_tags()` doesn't help since `the_terms()` is echoing the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy' )` instead of `the_terms()`

This will return an array of term objects.  You can access the term names by doing the following:

```
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    $custom_taxonomy = the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy');
endwhile;

// Print the term names
foreach ( $custom_taxonomy as $term ) {
  echo $term->name;
}
```

Check out the codex for more information on [get_the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)

Comment: I just did the song and dance through the core and found this out. But I had to use `$custom_taxonomy = array_shift($custom_taxonomy);` with no foreach loop as I was using only one taxonomy at a time